# Boost-spirit-karma and boost-variant "concepts" related to auto generators

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-variant, boost-spirit-karma

I need to deserialize a `std::vector<boost::variant<..>>` with decoration supplied by other objects.

One of the things the "decoration" enables is a empty entry in the vector. I have hit a brick wall in my real implementation. However, I have managed to shrink wrap it. Code that compiles :

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>

namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

typedef boost::variant<boost::int32_t, boost::int64_t> custom_variant;

int main()
{
    using karma::generate;

    custom_variant v;

    std::string temp;

    std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> x(temp);

    std::cout << v;

    karma::generate(x, karma::auto_, v);
}
```

The offending changes, which attempt to implement a "undefined" type, along with the required concept.

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>

namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

struct undefined{};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & out, undefined const & undefined)
{
    return out;
}

typedef boost::variant<undefined,boost::int32_t, boost::int64_t> custom_variant;

int main()
{
    using karma::generate;

    custom_variant v;

    std::string temp;

    std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> x(temp);

    std::cout << v;

    karma::generate(x, karma::auto_, v);
}
```

If I comment out the `karma::generate` step, `std::cout` is a valid expression (Boost::variant [`OutputStreamable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/variant/reference.html#variant.concepts.bounded-type)). Spirit requires that generators be given types which are `OutputStreamable`(spirit::karma [`OutputStreamable`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/tutorials/num_list.html#spirit.karma.tutorials.num_list.generate_output_from_arbitrary_data)) and the variant above should be `OutputStreamable` since I have made the `undefined` type`OutputStreamable` as a no-op.

What gives ? :(

I'm really beginning to question weather the C++ template mechanism is worth it when using libraries with > 2 levels of template indirection. Perhaps I should go back to straight-c.

**Edit 1:**

Ok, Clang gave me a sensible `first` error...

`error: no type named 'properties' in 'boost::spirit::karma::no_auto_mapping_exists'`

Now I got to figure out how to map undefined as a no-op to get a clean conversion. This [spirit documentation entry](http://error%3a%20no%20type%20named%20%27properties%27%20in%20%27boost%3a%3aspirit%3a%3akarma%3a%3ano_auto_mapping_exists%27) (and [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize/auto/create_generator.html) in specific) describes what I need to look into. Is there a generic undefined type provided by spirit or one defined in boost, that spirit already maps as a no-op ?

**Edit 2:**

`std::vector<boost::optional<boost::variant<..>>>` is beginning to look quite appealing since spirit provides type-deduction for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest to use `spirit::unused_type` for that purpose as it already is 'known' to Spirit and it has an `operator<<()` predefined (but any other type will do) - not that you really need that operator for Karma in the first place.

In addition, you have to provide a specialization for `create_generator` (as you suspected):

```
namespace boost { namespace spirit { namespace traits
{
    template <>
    struct create_generator<spirit::unused_type>
    {
        typedef spirit::karma::eps_type type;

        static type call()
        {
            return spirit::karma::eps;
        }
    };
}}}
```

which will map `unused_type` to `karma::eps`. This seems to be exactly what you need as `eps` eats the attribute without generating anything, while succeeding always. If you go this route you will not need to utilize `optional<>`.

Comment: thank you, as always. since I have the option, I will provide the mapping for `undefined`, as it already used in my QI code, and it lets me firewall spirit behind my own interface :D I'm beginning to see the power TMP extension brings. Just wish C++0x didn't drop "concepts".